# Import Data issue from CSV to AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory, read.csv

I have a problem importing phone numbers from a CSV file based on email addresses to Active directory using a PowerShell script.
The table contains:

```
mail;telephoneNumber
toto@domaine.com;88888888
tata@domaine.com;99999999
```

here’s the code I’m running but it shows me an error message, or I don’t see why there’s this message:

```
Import-module ActiveDirectory 
Import-CSV E: scripts list.csv | 
     ForEach-Object {
         Write-Host "telephoneNumber $($_.telephoneNumber)"
         Get-ADUser -Filter "mail -like '$($_.mail)'" | 
     Set-ADUser -telephoneNumber $_. telephoneNumber}
```

**Here is the error message:**

```
telephoneNumber
Set-ADUser: Unable to find a parameter corresponding to the name «telephoneNumber».
Character E: scripts employeeid.ps1:6: 14
+   Set-ADUser -telephoneNumber $_. telephoneNumber}
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo   : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId: NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

NB: I am a beginner in the subject

Thank you well in advance for your help

---

I tried this code too but still the same problem.

```
Import-module ActiveDirectory 
             
Import-CSV "E:\scripts\liste.csv" | % { 

$telephoneNumber = $_.telephoneNumber 

$mail= $ail_.m
Set-ADUser $telephoneNumber -mail $mail

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LDAP property `telephoneNumber` is known as `OfficePhone` in PowerShell and LDAP property `mail` has a PowerShell equivalent called `EmailAddress`.
Cmdlet `Set-ADUser` does not have a parameter called `telephoneNumber`, but it **does** have `OfficePhone`, so a rewrite of your code would be

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 
Import-Csv -Path 'E:\scripts\list.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "mail -eq '$($_.mail)'" # or use PS equivalent 'EmailAddress'
    if ($user) { 
        Write-Host "Setting telephoneNumber $($_.telephoneNumber) for $($user.Name)"
        $user | Set-ADUser -OfficePhone $_.telephoneNumber

        # if you do want to use LDAP property telephoneNumber, you can use below
        # $user | Set-ADUser -replace @{telephoneNumber = $($_.telephoneNumber)}
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Could not find user with EmailAddress $($_.mail)"
    }
}
```

P.S. you made some typos when posting:

- `E: scripts list.csv` is missing the backslashes
- `$_. telephoneNumber` has a space between the dot and the property name

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked when I made the change you asked for, a thousand thanks